# Amazon SNS: an offline mock

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Is there an AMAZON-SNS mock?
That is, some non-hosted version that I can use for testing or for offline cases? Preferably with the same API.

Like elasticMQ is for SQS?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really need a service you can try https://github.com/s12v/sns

Another option would be mocking. SNS is a HTTP service, so you can mock responses in your application.

Answer (score 8):

[LocalStack - A fully functional local AWS cloud stack](https://localstack.cloud/)

> LocalStack provides an easy-to-use test/mocking framework for
>   developing Cloud applications.
>
> Currently, the focus is primarily on supporting the AWS cloud stack.
>
> LocalStack spins up the following core Cloud APIs on your local
>   machine:
>
> ```
> API Gateway at http://localhost:4567
> Kinesis at http://localhost:4568
> DynamoDB at http://localhost:4569
> DynamoDB Streams at http://localhost:4570
> Elasticsearch at http://localhost:4571
> S3 at http://localhost:4572
> Firehose at http://localhost:4573
> Lambda at http://localhost:4574
> SNS at http://localhost:4575
> SQS at http://localhost:4576
> Redshift at http://localhost:4577
> ```

Comment: Is there any GUI to access SNS and SQS for the open version LocalStack, besides the very limited one included?